# EF Core Eager loading performance extremely slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2, entity-framework-core-2.2

I perform eager loading in production and it extremely slow it will get the website not responding here is my sample code

```
AppDbContext.Employees
        .Include(e => e.Employments)
            .ThenInclude(e => e.Department)
        .Include(e => e.Employments)
            .ThenInclude(e => e.Position)
        .Where(predicate).Tolist();
```

I `Take(20)` records of employee each employee has 5 - 10 employment records and each employment record i include the department and position. Why i take so long to retrieve the data?

Comment: You need to chain`Take` method, after `Where` if you want EF to incorporate that into SQL, otherwise you'll fetch all the records from database, and then get first 20, from in memory collection.

Comment: Do you `Take(20)` before or after the `ToList()` call? If so, you're loading everything from the DB to the memory, and only take 20 records from memory.
If you're genuinely instructing the database to only return 20 rows, enable entity framework core logging and post generated SQL code.

Comment: Yes I `Take(20)` before `ToList()`

Comment: Is lazy loading affect the eager loading? and by default lazy loading is disabled in asp.net core 2.2?

Comment: `options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;` make the performance slow